# Отступы текста от CheckBox

Tags: android, android-layout

Здравствуйте, возникла небольшая проблемка. Я на протяжении нескольких месяцов разрабатывал приложение под Android 5.0+. Настала пора заняться оптимизацией под Android 4.

Одной из первой проблем, с которой я столкнулся, стала отсутствие отступа текста у CheckBox:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На Android 5,0+ таких проблем не возникает, отступ есть. Первое, что пришло в голову - добавить отступ в коде. Текст двигается, все нормально, но на Android 5 он тоже двигается, что не есть хорошо, т.к. там отступы становятся просто огромными.

Интересным фактом является отсутствие данной проблемы у такого View-элемента, как RadioButton

Comment: А попробуйте AppCompatCheckBox вместо него из библиотеки поддержки, может поможет

Comment: AppCompat элементы в таких ситуациях обычно спасают...

Comment: Спасибо большое! Использование AppCompatCheckBox решило проблему!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня была подобная проблема проверка, решал так - если версия андроида меньше 5(программно проверял) устанавливал `padding`. По всей видимости баг sdk.